# How can I use vlookup for one value and return multiple corresponding values in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

Could someone please help me understand what formula or what I can do to enter in one value and have all the values populated based off that one value. Below is the excel sheet I have.

```
261 201421      King    WV1     US$11,823   US$15,060   US$7,074    US$7,008    0.90%   59.80%  47.00%
261 Standard    Wk19    W1      US$6,863    US$538      US$199      US$209      -4.60%  2.90%   37.00%
261 Standard    Wk19    W2      US$6,650    US$48       US$109      US$88       24.80%  1.60%   226.80%
261 WK18        12pk    40oz    US$13,836   US$17,500   US$13,979   US$12,781   9.40%   101.00% 79.90%
261 WK19        Choc    HTM     US$7,940    US$7,930    US$6,307    US$6,363    -0.90%  79.40%  79.50%
261                             US$47,112   US$41,076   US$27,668   US$26,449   4.60%   58.70%  67.40%
262 201421      King    WV1     US$9,712    US$12,719   US$5,090    US$5,802    -12.30% 52.40%  40.00%
262 Standard    Wk19    W1      US$6,724    US$661      US$353      US$436      -19.10% 5.20%   53.40%
262 Standard    Wk19    W2      US$4,504    US$49       US$157      US$231      -32.00% 3.50%   320.80%
262 WK18        12pk    40oz    US$12,148   US$17,245   US$11,035   US$11,117   -0.70%  90.80%  64.00%
262 WK19        Choc    HTM     US$7,490    US$7,403    US$4,352    US$5,292    -17.80% 58.10%  58.80%
262                             US$40,578   US$38,077   US$20,987   US$22,878   -8.30%  51.70%  55.10%
263 201421      King    WV1     US$14,880   US$19,666   US$7,423    US$7,277    2.00%   49.90%  37.70%
263 Standard    Wk19    W1      US$13,244   US$1,787    US$883      US$887      -0.40%  6.70%   49.40%
263 Standard    Wk19    W2      US$9,865    US$243      US$373      US$343      8.90%   3.80%   153.40%
263 WK18        12pk    40oz    US$20,862   US$23,600   US$23,808   US$23,803   0.00%   114.10% 100.90%
263 WK19        Choc    HTM     US$11,440   US$11,350   US$9,754    US$9,221    5.80%   85.30%  85.90%
263                             US$70,291   US$56,647   US$42,241   US$41,531   1.70%   60.10%  74.60%
```

when I search for 262 in the first column.

I want all the results in the 2nd column to show.

Comment: Where do you want these results to show? What does the desired outcome look like?

Comment: Indicating what you want to do with the values would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the autofilter and then filter on the value in column A. This will hide all rows that don't have that value in column A.

You can use Advanced Filter to automatically copy a filtered result to another range. Here is a [Microsoft article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx) on how to use Advanced filter.